# Binding to DataGrid with two-dimensional data and MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

In my actual project I have to display and modify unit numbers of multiple product-frame sizes in a WPF-DataGrid regarding the MVVM-Model.
For this, each frame size has multiple unit numbers from certain years.

My model has the following structure:

1. Frame Size

   ```
   class Framesize
   {
       public ObservableCollection<UnitNumber> UnitNumbers { get; set; }

       ...
   }
   ```
2. Unit number

   ```
   class UnitNumber
   {
       public int Year { get; set; }
       public int Number { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Actually, this is a very simple, but two-dimensional structure (frame size `x` year). Indeed, the DataGrid layout is the hard thing:

The desired layout is shown here: [DataGrid Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPNQP.png).
The DataGrid should be able to contain multiple frame sizes. For this, the columns with the years are supposed to be calculated from the least and eldest year over all frame sizes.
The rows should contain the frame size label and the unit numbers for the corresponding years.

On top, changes in the DataGrid should be automatically passed to the model over a binding due to the MVVM-Model. For example, when the user changes the unit number for a certain frame size in a certain year.

In the ViewModel, I've declared the variable `UnitNumbersList`, which is bound to the DataGrid over XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,45,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UnitNumbersList}"/>
```

Now the question is, what a variable this should be?

---

For this suppose, I thought about a DataTable because it can be created easily and programmatically. So the allocation to the binding variable in the ViewModel is the generated DataTable.
Sadly, I am not able to pass changed values over the binding to the model, wherefor the DataTable-approach is only good for displaying the values from the model and is not suitable for me.

So how can I fix this problem with a preferably simple solution?

Comment: The DataTable is editable, but the made changes are not passed to the model. When I refresh the DataTable, the old values are displayed and not the ones, I have entered before.

Comment: Even when I create a new DataTable from other Model Classes? If you want, I can post my code here for the DataTable creation.